# How to update checkbox form status after getting data from local storage in Nextjs

Tags: checkbox, next.js, react-hooks, local-storage

After getting data from local storage the data is not updated. In the list there are items shown checked/unchecked according initalData not according data from local storage.

```js
const [allFields, setAllFields] = useState(initialData);

useEffect(() => {
      const getData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`${collection}_activeList`));
      const items = getData ? getData : initialData
    setAllFields(items)
  }, []);

  return(
 /.../
       allFields.map((item) => {
        const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(item.checked);
        return (
                <li key={shortid()}>
                    <Form.Check
                        type="checkbox"
                        label={item.label}
                        checked={isChecked}
                        onChange={() => {
                   /.../
                            setIsChecked((prev) => !prev);
                        }}
                    ></Form.Check>
                </li>
           )
       /.../
)
```

`

I am sure that data from local storage is read but it is not used.